# Why vue.js type check for props failed even I use "Object as PropType<GeographicCoordinate | null>"?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, typechecking, vue-props

Context: vue.js (^3.2.13) + Typescript + Composition API + visual studio code

file type.ts:

```
export class GeographicCoordinate {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  altitude?: number;

  constructor(latitude: number, longitude: number, altitude?: number) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.altitude = altitude;
  }
}
```

component1.vue:

```
import { GeographicCoordinate } from '@/interfaces/type';
const props = defineProps({
  geographicCoordinate: {
    type: Object as PropType<GeographicCoordinate | null>, 
    required: true }
});
```

page.vue:

```
<template>
  <component1
    :geographic-coordinate="clickedGeographicCoordinate" @save-event="saveEvent">. 
  </component1>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { GeographicCoordinate } from '@/interfaces/type';
  var clickedGeographicCoordinate = ref<GeographicCoordinate | null>(null);
</script>
```

My visual code didn't hint and error here.
But when I open it in my Chrome, in console, there is error:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "geographicCoordinate". Expected Object, got Null

Why vue runtime hint null is not accepted?

And what is the best practice if a component accept a prop value be an instance of a cless or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual underlying issue is that you have `required: true` which is in direct opposition to a `null` value.  `null` is an intentional absence, which means you might as well have not sent any prop value at all for `geographic-coordinate`.  If the prop can be null, then it must not truly be required.  Remove the requirement and the warning should vanish.

```
const props = defineProps({
  geographicCoordinate: {
    type: Object as PropType<GeographicCoordinate | null>
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi @yoduh, thanks. It works after I removed required.

Comment: But, props geographicCoordinate is required in compoent1. In page.vue, clickedGeographicCoordinate is generated by user click action. What is the best practive for this? I have posted another question related to this situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76206723/what-is-the-best-practice-to-pass-null-to-a-required-props-in-component-in-vuejs