# What is the best practice to pass null to a required props in component in vuejs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, typechecking, vue-props

Stack: vuejs (3.2) + composition API + Typescript + Visual studio code

file type.ts:

```
export class GeographicCoordinate {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  altitude?: number;

  constructor(latitude: number, longitude: number, altitude?: number) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.altitude = altitude;
  }
}
```

component1.vue:

```
import { GeographicCoordinate } from '@/interfaces/type';
const props = defineProps({
  show: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  geographicCoordinate: {
    type: Object as PropType<GeographicCoordinate | null>, 
    required: true }
});
```

page.vue:

```
<template>
  <component1
    v-model:show="show"
    :geographic-coordinate="clickedGeographicCoordinate" @save-event="saveEvent">. 
  </component1>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { GeographicCoordinate } from '@/interfaces/type';
  var show = ref(false);
  var clickedGeographicCoordinate = ref<GeographicCoordinate | null>(null);
</script>
```

The variable clickedGeographicCoordinate is initiated to be null at first. And clickedGeographicCoordinate is generated by user click.

The variable show is used to control the visibility of component1. When show is set to true, clickedGeographicCoordinate is guranteed to be not null.
Now the problem here is that, vue raise warning in browser say that

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "geographicCoordinate". Expected Object, got Null

How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using composition API with Typescript, you should be able to define your props this way:

```ts
import { GeographicCoordinate } from '@/interfaces/type';

const props = defineProps<{
  show: boolean;
  geographicCoordinate: null | GeographicCoordinate;
}>();
```

Using Typescript definition you can more easily define your prop types and use `null` as a prop type. If you happen to use `null` as a prop type in options API, it will only disable prop type checking at runtime.

Also, you can conditionally display your component depending of whether your `geographicCoordinate` are defined or not, and this way you don't need to assert and check that both types could be used within your component

Comment: There are no defineProps args,  This removes type checking at runtime

Comment: Actually this is a Build time macro, what you write in the Generic part will be transformed when you build your app and it will validate at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. IIRC, there was something impractical with this approach. It looks like it won't do good in this case any way, " If the type is a reference to an imported type, the inferred result will be foo: null (equal to any type) "

Comment: From where do you quote that ?
Given the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props): _The interface or object literal type can contain references to types imported from other files, however, the generic argument itself passed to defineProps cannot be an imported type._

Meaning the inferred type will be correct, but the runtime type should be coerced to `object | null` because strict type validation doesn't exist with TS types. You can eventually write your own prop validator in this case

Comment: There is also this page about prop validation: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation
_If using Type-based props declarations , Vue will try its best to compile the type annotations into equivalent runtime prop declarations. For example, `defineProps<{ msg: string }>` will be compiled into `{ msg: { type: String, required: true }}`._

Comment: Here https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#type-only-props-emit-declarations . `geographicCoordinate: GeographicCoordinate` will be compiled to `geographicCoordinate: { type: null, required: true }`, not `geographicCoordinate: { type: Object, required: true }`. It looks inferior in this regard. Will likely not make any difference to null | GeographicCoordinate because null check would require custom prop validator any way

Answer (score 0):

You can handle component1 visibility by v-if, when show is false or geographicCoordinate is null, the component is not display and processing data.